# Error when trying to run an integration test

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, integration-testing, asp.net-core-7.0

When trying to run an integration test in .NET 7.0, I'm facing the following issue:

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (testhost.deps.json) was not found:
> package: 'Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities', version: '17.7.2-release-23578-01'
> path: 'Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.dll'

This has occurred with different dependencies before, but a simple `dotnet add package` solved the problem. `Microsoft.TestPlatform` is referenced in the `.csproj`, but it doesn't seem to care.

Any solutions to this? I'm just trying to run a simple lab.